# Каскады Хаара, в чём разница

Tags: python, opencv

Есть на гите несколько xml файлов для определения лиц: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades  default, два alt и tree. Чем они конкретно у них отличаются, можно про это где-то почитать?

Comment: в этих XML файлах сверху есть короткий комментарий, например `Stump-based 24x24 discrete(?) adaboost frontal face detector`. Ну а дальше гуглить... )

Answer (score 0):

В начале файла есть пояснения, привожу русский перевод

- haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml: Дискретный Фронтальный детектор лица на алгоритме [adaboost](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) c ядром 24x24 на основе культей.
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml: Фронтальный детектор лица  на алгоритме [adaboost](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) 20x20 ( назван нежный, то есть он вернет больше мэтчей с меньшим качеством)
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml: Фронтальный детектор лица на алгритме [adaboost](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) и [решающих деревьев](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-adaboost-for-decision-tree-ff8f07d2851) c ядром 20x20 (назван нежный, то есть он вернет больше мэтчей с меньшим качеством)
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml: Фронтальный детектор лица на алгритме [adaboost](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) c ядром 20x20. Этот детектор использует дерево классификаторов вместо каскада. (назван нежный, то есть он вернет больше мэтчей с меньшим качеством)
  ядро - это [ядро свертки](https://www.machinelearningmastery.ru/types-of-convolution-kernels-simplified-f040cb307c37/)

Comment: Какой-то странноватый перевод. Что за основа культей? И ещё про эти мэтчи не понял. Вроде наоборот который 24 на 24 возвращает больше определённых лиц, чем альтернативные.